# ncurses program will print white on black no matter what color i set it to

Tags: ncurses, curses

I have an ncurses-based text application i am writing. I have a function called colorPlot:

```
void colorPlot(int x, int y, int foregroundColor, int backgroundColor, char plotChar)
{
    init_pair(0, foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(0));
    mvaddch(y, x, plotChar);
}
```

But whenever i try to call it in my main function:

```
int main(void) {
    initscr();
    start_color();

    colorPlot(1, 1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE, '@');

    refresh();

    getch();

    endwin();
}
```

It only prints white-on-black. Why isn't it printing red-on-white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color pair 0 (see manual for [start_color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-Routine-Descriptions)) is reserved:

> color pair 0 is special; it denotes "no color".
>
> Color pair 0 is assumed to be white on black,  but  is
> actually whatever the terminal implements before color
> is initialized.  It cannot be modified by the application.